# How to make facebook login button use the bootstrap form-control?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, facebook

I´m implementing a facebook login to my website.
I use Bootstrap as my framework.

Now i´d like the facebook button look like, and be "size-controlled" byt bootstrap "form-control".
[image]

**FACEBOOK**

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
```

**BOOTSTRAP**

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger form-control">Registrera</a>
```

I´ve tried to simply add "form-control" as a class for the facebook btn, with no result.
I´ve also tried to set the width of the facebook btn to 100%;

So, how can i make the facebook btn resposive with bootstraps class "form-control" ?

**UPDATE**

```
<div class="fb-login-button btn form-control" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: You may use class btn-facebook on button

Comment: @geminiousgoel Does´nt work!

Comment: what exactly you are asking? CSS not working? may add width:444px under style. Should work

Comment: Have you try to add btn and  form-control classes together in fb button?

Comment: @geminiousgoel I´d like the facebook button. To have the same with as my bootsrap button. The size of my bootstrap btn is set by class "form-control" and i´d like to use it on the facebook btn as well. But it is not working. The facebook btn is handled by facebook.

Comment: @Aim Check update.

Comment: I see. Note: bootstrap button classes are ment to work with specific tags like button, anchor and input. And from your code you are using a div. Try to use our evolving of the above tag, may be anchor as your registration button

Comment: That Facebook button renders as an iframe, you have little control over it. If you want more control, I’d suggest you use your own button instead, that you can style however you like - and then use FB.login onclick to trigger login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add custom CSS below:

```
div.fb-login-button.fb_iframe_widget_fluid{ display: block !important; }
div.fb-login-button.fb_iframe_widget_fluid span, div.fb-login-button.fb_iframe_widget_fluid span iframe { width: 100% !important; }
```

works on Version 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Adding data width 100% to your soultion works even better, it's actually centered and responsive.

```
<div class="btn form-control pt-3 fb-login-button" data-width="100%"...
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to wokr